# Test contain no key words

Tags: robotframework

[New to Robot Frame Work, couldn't understand whats wrong!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjhlZ.png)

Here I am trying to read a json file and the test is failing saying that there are no keywords, what have I done wrong?

Comment: You should have pasted the text, instead of using an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test case name is the same as the keyword you defined. The test case does not have any step, just the name.

You need to add a step calling a keyword.